# Recover a field linked to another field in an automatic way

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm new in netsuite and I have to prove myself front of my boss.
My problem is how can I get to a sublist and retrieve a field linked to another field in an automatic way when creating a new line.

```html
function taxCode_fieldChanged(context) {
 var stCodeTax = nlapiGetFieldValue('cust_taxcode');
 var labelCategory = nlapiGetFieldValue('name');
 var currentFormRec = context.currentRecord;
 var sublistName = context.sublistId;
 var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
 var lineNum = scriptContext.lineNum;
 var colNum = scriptContext.columnNum;

 for (var l = 1; l < lineNum; l++) {
  for (var c = 1; c < colNum; c++) {

   if (sublistName === 'Expenses' && sublistFieldName === 'Category') {
    currentFormRec.setValue({
     fieldId : 'tax code',
     value : stCodeTax
    });
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: scriptContext is not defined anywhere. Should it be context instead? Is the field in a matrix?

Comment: yes the field in a matrix

Comment: In SuiteScript 2.0 rec.setValue() is used to set body fields. rec.setSublistValue() is used to set sublist fields and rec.setMatrixSublistValue() is used to set fields in a matrix, so perhaps the way the field is set should be reconsidered. I also noticed that it looks like SuiteScript 1.0 and 2.0 are used within the same script, which is not correct. What version is the script record? Which version do you want to write? Also, in the if statement the sublist and field name are usually lowercase. Hope this helps.